# R: ggplot2 stat_bin2d legend count as percentage instead

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to plot coordinates as a heatmap with the following codes:

```
stat_bin2d(bins = 20)
```

AND

```
scale_fill_gradient(name = "Count", 
                      low = "#ffffff",
                      high = "#000000",
breaks = seq(0, 500, by=10), labels = scales::percent)
```

before I added "labels = scales::percent", the legend would just show a range up to the highest count i.e. 400 (out of 500).

I wanted it to show as a percentage instead i.e. 80%. But all the above code does is add two extra 00's and a percentage sign at the end i.e. 400 00%.

I've searched all over S/O and the web for a simple way to do this, but can't seem to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `labels` argument only changes the text that is displayed at the legend, not the actual values itself. To get appropriate percentage labels, you should change the fill to `after_stat(density)` (recall that densities integrate to 1 and thus by choosing density, every bin contains the fraction of total observations in that bin). The density is documented in the 'computed variables' section of `?stat_bin2d`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x, y)) + xlim(4, 10) + ylim(4, 10) +
  stat_bin2d(aes(fill = after_stat(density))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Percent", 
                      labels = scales::percent)
#> Warning: Removed 478 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin2d).
```

[image]